# Loadrunner - Getting message in HTTP response "HTML parsing not performed for Content-Type "application/xml""

Tags: http, http-headers, loadrunner

The send and receive content on the server I work on is with type `"application/xml"`.

On my init section I added the below line to automatically to add to all my header requests

```
web_add_auto_header("Content-Type","application/xml");
```

When I run the script, I get response header showing the correct content-type but in the boo day I get message:

```
351-byte response headers for "http://172.29.67.68/svc/bw/cti/monitor/event/bw_perfuser1000_60a439f7-599d-4fe1-baa6-598391312954" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=5)
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2019 18:20:09 GMT\r\n
Content-Length: 681\r\n
Content-Type: application/xml\r\n
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
no-store\r\n
Pragma: no-cache\r\n
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=96\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
```

message I get:

```
HTML parsing not performed for Content-Type "application/xml" ("ParseHtmlContentType" Run-Time Setting is "TEXT").
```

To fix this issue, I need to add the below line before each request

```
web_add_header("Content-Type","application/xml");
```

Can anyone please explain why I need to explicitly mention the content-type before each request although I used the `web_add_auto_header()` function?

Comment: Is there maybe any revert auto header in script?

Comment: is the call in question in the action and not in the init.   Scoping

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP protocol, you need to specific Request Header Fields in HTTP request. The detail of HTTP Header please refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).